# how to remove rows based on some specific criteria

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I have a data frame like the table below. based on the ranks i provided I want to remove rows in this way.
Data..

```
name    date    rank
angel   7/25/2017   3
maggie  8/8/2017    2
maggie  8/8/2017    1
maggie  8/8/2017    2
maggie  8/8/2017    3
smith   8/16/2017   1
smith   8/16/2017   3
laura   9/26/2017   2
laura   9/26/2017   1
laura   9/26/2017   2
laura   9/27/2017   3
lisa    9/5/2017    1
lisa    9/5/2017    3
bill    7/20/2017   1
bill    7/20/2017   3
bill    7/21/2017   3
bill    7/31/2017   3
bill    8/1/2017    3
bill    8/7/2017    1
tomy    8/1/2017    3
```

What I want to do is for every given name - if there is one date- I want to keep that row but for same name- same date if there are different ranks-I want to select in order and remove the rest. so for example- if bill has 4 rows in the same date- but different ranks_ I want to remove all ranks and keep only "1" with all row information

The output I want is like this:

```
name    date    rank
angel   7/25/2017   3
maggie  8/8/2017    1
smith   8/16/2017   1
laura   9/26/2017   1
laura   9/27/2017   3
lisa    9/5/2017    1
bill    7/20/2017   1
bill    8/7/2017    1
tomy    8/1/2017    3
```

Can someone please help me with that

Comment: Please post the expected outcome and as always, please post what you have tried so far and state where you are stuck.

Comment: What is your expected output? Please add it to your question.

Comment: My expected output is:
name date rank
angel 7/25/2017 3
maggie 8/8/2017 1
smith 8/16/2017 1
laura 9/26/2017 1
laura 9/27/2017 3
lisa 9/5/2017 1
bill 7/20/2017 1
bill 8/7/2017 1
tomy 8/1/2017 3

Comment: Are you looking for `df.groupby(['name', 'date']).rank.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1))`?

Comment: @Blue NO! Add it to your question.

Comment: @Coldspeed- I tried editing my question but I dont see an option there

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ your suggestion didnt quite work for me. I gave me another column with some numbers. and more importantly_it didnt remove the un necessary columns. like below:
name date rank
angel 7/25/2017 3
maggie 8/8/2017 1
smith 8/16/2017 1
laura 9/26/2017 1
laura 9/27/2017 3
lisa 9/5/2017 1
bill 7/20/2017 1
bill 8/7/2017 1
tomy 8/1/2017 3

Comment: @Blue Please.... ADD DETAILS AND DATA TO YOUR QUESTION. I cannot understand _anything_ you post in the comments. Please understand.

Comment: Why does Bill have only 2 rows in the output when they have so many different dates?

Comment: Thanks @Coldspeed for helping- for any given date_ bill has one based on the rank_ I am for the most part interested in rank 1 but if there is no rank 1 given for any given date then go to rank 2 or in case 2 is not here then get 3

Comment: Is there any way I can code it using Python?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this answered by the following

```
`data = df.loc[df.groupby(['name', 'date'])['rank'].idxmin()]`
```

However, I would still like to know if a complex for loop can get that too. I am new to python and would love to learn more.
Thanks